# Start a list of processes, then terminate them

Tags: powershell, process

Using powershell how do you start some processes running, then kill them some time later?

I start processes using the following:

```
ps
Start-Process "notepad.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called run.ps1 with the following contents:

```
$apps = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]

$app = Start-Process "notepad.exe"  -passthru
$apps.Add($app)

$app = Start-Process "notepad.exe"  -passthru
$apps.Add($app)

Write-Host "Press any key to terminate ..."
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")

#Kill the running processes
foreach ($app in $apps) 
{
    Write-Host "Killing" ($app.Id -as [string])
    Stop-Process $app.Id
}
```

And now you can execute it using:

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  ./test.ps1
```